# convert a matrix(list of lists) into a square matrix in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

I want to convert the given matrices a, b into square matrices by inserting zeros wherever necessary

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
b = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

I want the output to be

```
a1 = [[1,2,0,0],[3,4,0,0],[5,6,0,0],[7,8,0,0]]
b1 = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8][0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

I have trouble installing numpy package on my machine. Any solution without the use of numpy would greatly help.

Thanks

Comment: OK. What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> a = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]]
>>> b = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]
>>>
>>> def matrix(a, n):
...     for row in a:
...         yield row + [0] * (n - len(row))
...     for i in range(len(a), n):
...         yield [0] * n
...
>>> list(matrix(a, 4))
[[1, 2, 0, 0], [3, 4, 0, 0], [5, 6, 0, 0], [7, 8, 0, 0]]
>>> list(matrix(b, 4))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This little function ought to do the trick:

```
def squarify(lst, n):
    for sublist in lst:
        while len(sublist) < n:
            sublist.append(0)

    while len(lst) < n:
        lst.append([0]*n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two pieces of information: the longest row, and the most number of columns.  To get longest row, assuming that you can assume that each matrix has a set number of rows, you need to do something like

```
rowAlen = len(a[0])
rowBlen = len(b[0])
longestRow = 0;
if rowAlen > rowBlen:
    longestRow = rowAlen
else:
    longestRow = rowBlen
```

Then you'll need to get the number of columns of the matrix with the most columns.

```
colAlen = len(a)
colBlen = len(b)
maxCol = 0;
if colAlen > colBlen:
    maxCol = colAlen
else:
    maxCol = colBlen
```

Now that you have longestRow and maxCol, you can manipulate matrices.

```
for x in range(0,maxCol):
    if colAlen <= x:
        a.append([])

    if colBlen <= x:
        b.append([])

    for y in range(0, longestRow):
        if len(a[x]) <= y:
            a[x].append(0)

        if len(b[x]) <= y:
            b[x].append(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the output you are looking for, as well as alter the original list if it was stored in a variable.

```
def matrize(L):
  msize = max(len(L), max([len(subL) for subL in L]))
  for item in L:
    while len(item)<msize: item.append(0)
  zrow = [0]*msize
  while len(L)< msize: L.append(zrow)
  return L
```